# IE7 throwing script error on jquery gallery ad-gallery (I think)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I have made a bit of a boo boo, by not keeping an eye on how my site development looks in the old browsers as I have gone along, now checking through ietester I am getting a script error in ie7.

the code it points to is line 172, char 5, I have put ************* in front of this line as indicated in view source, however since this line has no char 5 it could be anywhere in this area so I am not really sure where to go from here. Any help appreciated.

```
var galleries = $('.ad-gallery').adGallery({
            loader_image: 'loader.gif',
            width: 350,
            height: 300,
            animation_speed:1000,
            slideshow: {
                enable: true,
                autostart: true,
                speed: 10000,
                start_label: 'Start / ',
                stop_label: 'Stop Slideshow',
                stop_on_scroll: true,
                countdown_prefix: '[',
                countdown_sufix: ']',
         *************  },
            effect: 'fade',
            callbacks: {
                init: function(){this.preloadAll();}}
        });
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
        $('.tabcont').jScrollPane({showArrows:false});
        $(".tabclick").click(function(){
            $('.tabcont').jScrollPane({showArrows:false});
        });
```

This is all inside a document ready function with a load of other stuff I didn't think was relevent, if more of the code is needed please let me know. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last comma  in " countdown_sufix: ']', " is not needed as it is the last element in the array. Remove it and test again.

Sometimes, an error in a previous line ends being detected in the next one.

Comment: You sir are a speedy super star - works perfectly now - all because of a comma. I will accept your answer as 100% brilliant and right in 9 minutes when it lets me.